# how to use spring libraries in tomcat 7.0?

Tags: spring, tomcat, libraries

How to add the spring libraries in tomcat 7.0, Is it necessary to copy the spring libraries in "program files (X86 )/Apache software foundation/ tomcat 7.0/ lib" or just copying the entire spring library in c-drive is enough?

Comment: In addition to duffymo's answer, you might want to check out some Java classpath and web app  tutorials so you know *why* you're doing what you're doing, and why putting them somewhere on the c: drive isn't sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the Spring JARs that you need into the WEB-INF/lib directory of your WAR file.

If you put them in the Tomcat /lib folder they'll be available to all the apps deployed on Tomcat, but that may not be what you want.  You'll need all their dependencies too, of course.